# Creating Makefile for source file in parent directory

Tags: c, makefile

```
---src
    ---U
       ---B
         ---D
           ---L
             ---T
                ---F
                 main.c
                 Makefile
```

I have written a program in main.c which requires a custom header file residing inside directory L/. The implementation of the header functions is present in a source file (src.c)  in L/.

Thw source file src.c in turn depends on other custom source and header files which are present in the same dir as src.c or other top level dirs.

I want to write a MakeFile in F/ such that is is able to pick and choose those source and header files as required and create a binary.

I cannot edit/use the existing make files as this process needs to be decoupled from the exiting one and also requires a separate toolchain and CFLAGS.

I read about VPATH but I am not able to make my build work.

Following MakeFile is not working and complains about x.o and other object files not found.

```
all: prog

CC = clang-11

CFLAGS= -g -fsanitize=fuzzer
 
#INCLUDES = -I../../../../../B
  
INC = $(INCLUDES)
 
OBJS =  x.o qc.o dl.o l.o d.o
 
LIBS = -lcrypto -luuid

prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o prog $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

x.o: x.c  //do I need to specify other header file dependencies here?
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o x.o x.c

qc.o: qc.c
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o qc.o qc.c

dl.o: dl.c
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o dl.o dl.c

l.o: l.c
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -fsanitize=fuzzer -c -o l.o l.c

d.o: d.c
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o d.o d.c

clean: 
    rm -f *.o prog
```

I don't have experience with writing make files. Could you please help me correct this?

Comment: Do you really want to write a makefile? How about using cmake instead?

Comment: It is difficult to fix the makefile if we don't know the location of x.c and other source files. VPATH can be used, in this case, it need the list of the directories where are located the sources files. But, VPATH is not mandatory here. You need to write the relative path of the source files ../../T/source.c so that make could find it.

Comment: Tips: to transform your source file to object file you can do: ` $(SRC:.c=.o)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.o: x.c  //do I need to specify other header file dependencies here?
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o x.o x.c
```

No need more dependencies, but you need to provide the relative path of the file. Example:

```
x.o: ../../D/x.c  //do I need to specify other header file dependencies here?
    $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o x.o ../../D/x.c
```

Suggestion: simplify your tree, it is too complicated.

```
Folder
  src
  inc
  doc
```

Use of `VPATH`

It is mostly used to split the binary directory from the source directory. In this case, you have something like that:

```
OBJS = bin/a.o bin/b.o

VPATH = src
```

When GNU Make will try to create a.o, it will find src/a.c.

Comment: Shouldn't the second `$(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o x.o x.c` be `$(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o x.o ../../D/x.c`? Also, you switched from using forward slash directory separators to backslashes later on in the answer.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the answer. I was able to correct the file based on your suggestions. I am not at liberty to modify the directory structure, so, working with relative paths worked for me.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, that is the correct way. I was still getting a - No such file or directory error until I used the command like - $(CC) $(INC) -g -c -o x.o ../../D/x.c (this is the correct way)